# Python script running fine on Windows, but get json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: under the Debian

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, beautifulsoup

I made one BeautifulSoup script, which is on Windows and seems working fine on it, now I would like to run the script on Debian, but I got an error, and I haven't got idea why,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
import requests
import urllib3
import time
import random

user_agents = [
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/101.0.0.0",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  ]
random_user_agent = random.choice(user_agents)
headers = {
    'User-Agent': random_user_agent
}

url = "https://www.alza.hu/intel-core-i9-13900ks-d7603014.htm"
session_object = requests.Session()
response = session_object.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=20)
get_source = (response).text
print(response.status_code)
time.sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_source, "lxml")
json_schema = soup.find_all('script', attrs={'type': 'application/ld+json'})[1]
json_file = json.loads(json_schema.get_text())
sku = json_file['sku']
price = json_file['offers']['price']
stock = json_file['offers']['availability']
print(sku, price, stock)
```

On Windows 10 it works perfectly, not having any trouble with it.

On Debian 11:

200
Traceback (most recent call last):
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I checked all dependencies same each OS,
I checked the sample URL on Debian, and loading fine (so not a network-blocking issue)

If I try to print 'json_schema' works fine,

```
200
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Product",
"name": "Intel Core i9-13900KS",
"description": "Processzor - 24 magos, 32-szálas, 3,2 GHz, Turbo Boost technológ                                                                                                                                                        iával akár 6 GHz, Boost technológiával akár 6 GHz, 36 MB L3 cache, TDP 253 W, In                                                                                                                                                        tel UHD Graphics 770, Raptor Lake, hűtő nélkül, csak Intel 600, 700 series chips                                                                                                                                                        et, Intel LGA1700 foglalat ",
"image": "https://image.alza.cz/products/BOi913900ks/BOi913900ks.jpg?width=190&h                                                                                                                                                        eight=190",
"aggregateRating": {
"@type": "AggregateRating",
"ratingValue": "4.6",
"ratingCount": "15"
},
"offers": {
"@type": "Offer",
"priceCurrency": "HUF",
"price": "322790",
"url": "https://www.alza.hu/intel-core-i9-13900ks-d7603014.htm",
"itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition",
"availability": "http://schema.org/OutOfStock"
},
"brand": "Intel",
"sku": "BOi913900ks",
"mpn": "BX8071513900KS   ",
"gtin13": "BOi913900ks"
}</script>
```

If I try to print 'json_file' I get error.

```
200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/scraper/alzalinux.py", line 28, in <module>
    json_file = json.loads(json_schema.get_text())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What `print(json_schema)` prints under debian?

Comment: I tryout,  print json_schema, and I got the required JSON, under debian.

Comment: There is a typo in one line, should be `response = session_object.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=20)`

Comment: Maybe there's a hidden character. Try `print(repr(json_schema))`

Comment: json_schema correctly print out, no issue,

Comment: If I run it, I get `<Response [200]>
BOi913900ks 322790 http://schema.org/OutOfStock
`.

Comment: And which OS do you run it?

Comment: I asked you to print json_schema hoping that you would edit your question and put the result there. OS shouldn't matter so your situation is subtle and needs additional information.

Comment: Edited, updated

Comment: Your json file might be in UTF-8 + BOM.  Transparent on Windows, not always on Linux.  BOM adds invisible character at the start of the file, the json decoder might choke on that.  And it does complain about line 1 column 1 (char 0) so look it up!

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-with-bom, user rsp's answer, it talks about json and BOM.